# whats the correct term for a "diamond" an directed acyclic graph?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

I want to talk about places in a directed acyclic graph where there is more than one path from node node to another. It's not a "cycle", what should I call it? I'm using the term "diamond", but that implies just four nodes, which is not right.

Comment: Is there even a term for this?

Comment: I'd just describe it as multiple edges from A to B.

Comment: Am I dense?  Why isn't it just a "cycle"?  Or do mean an entire graph that is a single list whose `end.next` points at `head`?  Like an [ouroboros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros)?

Comment: @jonnyGold: a *cycle* is a directed path that loops back to one of its nodes, this question sounds like it is talking about two distinct directed paths from one node to another.

Comment: @muistooshort: Ah. The word "diamond" grounded me in the circular buffer idea.  We're talking about two arcs coming into a particular node irrespective of cycle-ness.  How about calling it "multi-touch"?  Seem hip these days.

Comment: !Multi touch! I don't think so. I'll have to go with diamond, by the sound of it. I was hoping there was a proper graph-theoretic name.
The significance of DAGs without diamonds is that every node acts as the root of two trees - one going one way, one the other. The presence of diamonds means you have to check for duplicates.

Comment: @jonnyGold no, not just "two arcs coming into a node", but two different arcs that have an "upstream" node in common.

Comment: In that case, to make the name sounds more erudite how about prefixing "diamond" with the "degree" - how many incoming arcs that originate from an upstream node.  Your example would be a "2-diamond".  I could easily see a "3-diamond" or more if we're talking about real-world road maps, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

As you stated, the correct term is unlikely to be diamond graph, which already has a similar but slightly different [meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_graph).

It's ugly, but the graph you're referring to is a [homeomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_%28graph_theory%29) of the [dipole graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_graph). That is, you can simplify the graph by contracting any edge with in- and out-degree 1.

From past experience, graph theoretic terminology can be tough. If you've got friends or colleagues who are mathematicians, they should always be your first port of call in such cases. If you've got time up your sleeve, you can use a good reference on graph theory. I recommend either [Graph Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1846289696) by Bondy and Murty or [Graph Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3642142788) by Diestel. If neither are available, you could always try [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory), or one of the math related stackexchange sites.

Comment: So I suppose I am talking about dipole-free graphs, or graphs with no subgraph homeomorphic to a dipole. Way too much trouble :), but thanks for the info.